need to change the Input text color or background color of textbox of my checkout
On my checkout page-  mazequestadventurebooks.com/checkout2/  - the input field for the credit-debit card has a white background, white placeholder text, and white input text, making it impossible to see what is there or what is typed.
I've tried to access the checkout through appearance -> customize -> wordpress -> checkout, but the checkout section is unavailable and says the theme allows checkout editing through editor.
Try using the editor, and the wordpress block page does not give me colour options and the elementor page doesn't display the checkout of offer me colour options.

Figured it out!
Downloaded the royal elementor addon plugin, which includes a checkout section, and it allowed me to change the style colors of the checkout! (even though I was using the woocommerce built-in checkout!)
